# How to configure PhpStorm 10 for Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I have installed Laravel 5 on Windows via WAMP and Composer. Now please tell me how to configure PhpStorm 10 for Laravel 5.

[image: current status]

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4\php.exe C:/Users/Bansal/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration C:\wamp\www\laraveltest
Testing started at 3:43 AM ...

Process finished with exit code 1
Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.;C:\php\pear)
```

Comment: So .. are you trying to run PHPUnit tests? **In general:** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Comment: No, i am actually trying to run laravel on windows using wamp & phpstorm8

Comment: So .. why do you trying to execute PHPUnit tests? *(that's what you do based on your screenshot)*

Comment: Laravel specific manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm ; Running apps (Run/Debug Configurations): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/run-debug-configurations.html?search=run